# Concatenated dynamic PDO query safe from injection without bindparam

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo

I have page generating a list of records which I want to filter or narrow down by a number of possibilities.  Thus, I am looking at adding possible **"AND"** statements to the SQL query. User-generated data doesn't make it to the query except for the pagination which is passed to the LIMIT part of the query.

My Questions:

1. Is this open to injection after LIMIT because I'm not using bindParam?

   ```
   $start_record = $_GET['page'];
   $ids = array('pid_b', 'pid_l', 'pid_g' );
   $qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($ids) - 1) . '?';

   // THIS MY CONDITION FOR TESTING PURPOSES ONLY
   $testVar = 1;

   // NOW WE BUILD THE QUERY
   $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM inventory_tbl ";
   $sqlQuery .= "WHERE `consignor_record_id` IN ($qMarks) ';
   $sqlQuery .= ($testVar == 1 ? " AND `inventory_status` <> 'active' " : "");
   $sqlQuery .= "ORDER BY `created_date` DESC LIMIT $start_record, 50 ;";

   $productSearch = $dbh->prepare( $sqlQuery );
   ```

Comment: I don't believe it is aside from the `LIMIT` as you stated. And I'm curious as to how @cmorrissey thinks it is.

Comment: In the spirit of education, do you mind explaining?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, his question was is it open to injection after the `LIMIT` it absolutely is, he was not stating that it was open

Comment: Ah, yes. I read it wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, that detailed comment should be an answer. It's sufficiently answers the question.

Comment: @MarcusAdams You are right. I wasn't planning on making it that detailed but kept adding to it. Moved to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then yes, it is open to sql injection. One major sql injection issue is joining multiple queries together via union. If I knew how many columns the inventory_tbl had and the name of something else like the users table I could just send a page get value of `0 UNION ALL SELECT col1,col2 FROM USERS --` and it would essentially select zero rows from the inventory table and select all rows from the users table or similar. Or if that doesn't work, send a sub-query for the limit that would execute other code. Or even semi-colon to end select and any other query to execute in addition to first.

Comment: Thank you for explaining!  Is there a way to prevent it in PDO?

Comment: Since limit accepts a number you can check if is_numeric and cast as an int.

Answer (score 1):

**From PDO Wiki**

> When in emulation mode (which is on by default), PDO substitutes
>   placeholders with actual data. And with "lazy" binding (using array in
>   execute()), PDO treats every parameter as a string. As a result, the
>   prepared LIMIT ?,? query becomes LIMIT '10', '10' which is invalid
>   syntax that causes the query to fail.
>
> The solutions is turn emulation off (as MySQL can sort all
>   placeholders out properly).

```
$start_record =  1;//$_GET['page'];
$ids = array('pid_b', 'pid_l', 'pid_g' );
// THIS MY CONDITION FOR TESTING PURPOSES ONLY
$testVar = 1;
//Set up parameters for lazy binding
$params =$ids;//Fill array with ids
array_push($params,$testVar);
array_push($params,$start_record);
$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($ids) - 1) . '?';
// NOW WE BUILD THE QUERY
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM inventory_tbl ";
$sqlQuery .= "WHERE `consignor_record_id` IN ($qMarks) ";
$sqlQuery .= "AND $testVar == ? AND `inventory_status` <> 'active' " ;
$sqlQuery .= "ORDER BY `created_date` DESC LIMIT ?, 50 ;";
//To turn emulation off, one can run this code (or set in a connection options array):
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
$productSearch = $dbh->prepare($sqlQuery );
$productSearch->execute($params);
//Remove echos after testing
echo $sqlQuery;
echo "<br>";
var_dump($params);
```

**Result**

```
SELECT * FROM inventory_tbl WHERE `consignor_record_id` IN (?,?,?) AND 1 == ? AND `inventory_status` <> 'active' ORDER BY `created_date` DESC LIMIT ?, 50 ;
```

Params for lazy binding

```
  array(5) { [0]=> string(5) "pid_b" [1]=> string(5) "pid_l" [2]=> string(5) "pid_g" [3]=> int(1) [4]=> int(1) }
```

Answer (score 0):

This query is not safe from injection. You can inject via $_GET['page'].